# laravel getting error on using alias in joins 4.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Getting error as ORA-00905: missing keyword Position in laravel 4.1

> ->leftjoin('table1','table1.portid','=','ordertable.order_id')
>
> ->leftjoin('table2 as  dep','dep.portid','=','ordertable.departure')
>
> ->leftjoin('table2 as arr','arr.portid','=','ordertable.arrival')

On using alias for join 2(table2 as  dep) and 3 (table2 as arr) getting error, Can Someone let me know where I have to use as, am I correct with the syntax V4.1

Comment: The same query works works for me in 5.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

Just remove as its works

> ->leftjoin('table1','table1.portid','=','ordertable.order_id')
>
> ```
> ->leftjoin('table2 dep','dep.portid','=','ordertable.departure')
>
> ->leftjoin('table2 arr','arr.portid','=','ordertable.arrival')
> ```